# Sublime Text: regular expression: select specific lines of text that varu only with a number change per line?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have thousands of generated lines of JavaScript that I'm cleaning up in Sublime Text. I hope to gut out the non-used generated code. Here's an example of a line I want to select/remove using regex:

```
score.push({t:3.162, o:[{f:'metronome', a:0}]});
```

The only change for these lines is the t property:

```
score.push({t:[THIS CHANGES], o:[{f:'metronome', a:0}]});
```

How would I create a regular expression for this?

Thanks for the assist in advance!

Comment: Do you want a regex for `score.push({t:[THIS CHANGES], o:[{f:'metronome', a:0}]});`, or do you want a generic regex that will remove all lines that have a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
^score\.push\({t:\d+\.\d+, o:\[{f:'metronome', a:0}\]}\);$
```

will select the line

where

- `\d+` matches anydigits

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tC5zF2/1)

You can even use

```
^score\.push\({t:.*, o:\[{f:'metronome', a:0}\]}\);$
```

if anything can occure in the `t` property

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tC5zF2/2)

Comment: With some small adjustments, I was able to make this work using:

`^score\.push\(\{t:\d+\.\d+, o:\[\{f:'metronome', a:0\}\]\}\);$`

Then press the "Find All" button which worked as I had hoped. Thanks for the first answer!

Comment: @ChristopherStevens You are welcome. Glad to hear it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove *all* duplicate lines. The best you can do is create a new regex for every set of duplicate lines, like this:

```
^score\.push\({t:[0-9.], o:\[{f:'metronome', a:0}]}\);$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
score\.push\({t:[^,]*,\s+o:\[{f:'metronome',\s+a:0}\]}\);
```

Try this. This will remove all such lines. See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/13